# Spring MVC with JSON is not working via ajax call

Tags: json, spring, jquery, spring-mvc

I'm trying to set up a very simple "HelloWorld" Spring MVC that will respond with JSON to user requests.

I created this maven project http://www.filedropper.com/mvctest (7 kb).
To run it just use mvn jetty:run

And when it starts up, `http://localhost:8080/` will respond with

```
{"name":"John","age":25}
```

That's exactly what I wanted. Now instead of typing `http://localhost:8080/` into a browser I want to call it via ajax.

I created this simple html file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost:8080", 
            success: function(data) { alert("succsess") },
            error: function() { alert("error") }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

And a result is "error". I can see on server logs that controller was called. I can see in firebug a correct response with JSON, but for some reason JQuery is unable to parse it.

When I tried to call different URL that returns JSon - it worked.

http://ip.jsontest.com/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://ip.jsontest.com/", 
            success: function(data) { alert("succsess") },
            error: function() { alert("error") }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Result is success! I can see a couple of extra headers in server response in firebug, but I dont think its an issue here, and everything else is the same as in my project.

Any idea why http://ip.jsontest.com/ response can be correctly interpreted by JQuery and mine not?

Thanks,
Alex

P.S.: Here is a source of Controller handling requests

@Controller
   public class HomeController {

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

/**
 * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Person home(Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome home!");

    Person person = new Person("John", 25);
    return person;
}


public class Person{
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }   
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show the handler on the controller that is responding to the request?

Comment: Project with all sources can be download here http://www.filedropper.com/mvctest - its very small, only 7Kb.

And I updated question with Controller code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after many hours of trial and error I discovered that the following header needs to be added to Response

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
```

I created a Filter class that extends OncePerRequestFilter, which will add the above header to all Responses.

This solved my issue.

Comment: What browser did you use for debugging this issue? Must browsers log an error message to the console when it blocks cross origin requests.